# GNU/Linux distribution for network virus || malware identification

Tags: linux, distributions, malware

I'm looking for a GNU/Linux distro that I can install in transparent setup to look for infected hosts on a LAN. I don't need to stop viruses and malwares but only identify them and the host where they come from.

I don't necessarily need fancy graphics but I would like something pre-configured and possibly free. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is booting with a LiveCD and option for you?

Comment: Yes Tim i also like livecd

Comment: [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) perhaps?  It's a live CD distro designed for pen-testing but it probably has detection tools as well.  Also, you may be interested in the [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) software suite.

Comment: +1 for Backtrack. It has penetration testing tools with it by default that will be of great help. This is good ref and will be of help. http://sectools.org/

Answer (score 1):

[securityonion](http://securityonion.blogspot.com/) is a ubuntu based distribution for intrusion detection. In its default configuration, it uses snort or suricata and bro-ids to analyse network traffic (that you feed it for instance by configuring your firewall to send it to it, or by using port mirroring on a switch) for signs of malicious activity using rules from VRT or Emerging Threats.

It also comes with an armada of security tools, and tools to inspect traffic. It can also be configured to watch files being downloaded and query databases of malware.

Answer (score 0):

The "SystemRescueCD" distro is gentoo based and comes with at least ClamAV antivirus scanner on it. It might have had a few other AV tools as well.

http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

Comment: I know SystemRescuCD but it's not suited to my needs. What I'm looking for is a distro wich analyzes traffic passing throw a transparent server and reports for bad virus/malware traffic whith the host source IP address originating the threat.